# Convert Wordpress text with a function

Tags: wordpress, function

I am migrating a site into Wordpress from a very old CMS. In this CMS they import a csv file and inside that file in the cells they specify bullets with this shortcode text "|B|"

Is there a way to write a function that always converts those three characters into this code for me `"<br />&#150;"` inside the post editor?

Answer (score 0):

So are you importing that CSV once into WordPress, or doing it on a regular basis?

Why not do a find/replace on the CSV before import?

After import, do a find/replace in the post content in the database. [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace (optionally with grep) through all posts, pages, excerpts, comments, titles and meta.

Comment: I will be constantly importing new CSV files, that's why I am looking for something that automatically changes that in the post editor rather than a manual step. I saw this one time in a Youtube video and I can't remember where I saw it or how it was done :)

Comment: Why not do a find/replace on the CSV before import? You're going to have to write a CSV importer, and then add a function to find/replace that string.

Comment: I am dealing with an archive of CSV files, it's not very practical to do it that way.

Comment: Well, you need to show what you've tried. Take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LOAD+DATA+INFILE for examples and then look at http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0):

After searching for awhile I found that this plugin does exactly what I want: https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/

It doesn't actually provide me a function for the theme, but this accomplishes the exact task I had in mind.